# Burninate [dataset]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

There are currently 63 questions tagged [dataset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset), but [no tag wiki](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tags/dataset/info). I struggle mightily and unsuccessfully to find a good use of it in the DS.SE context.

- *Requests* for data are [migrated to OpenData](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/add-specific-migration-target-opendata), where they belong.
- Questions about specific aspects of big data can be tagged [bigdata](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bigdata).
- Questions about analyzing specific *types* of data can be tagged [time-series](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series) or similar.
- Questions about data formats can be tagged [data-formats](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-formats).
- Questions about cleaning data can be tagged [data-cleaning](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-cleaning).

And so forth. I can't imagine a good reason for *filtering* for [dataset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset). It seems like [dataset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset) is empty for all intents and purposes here. Let's burninate it.

Thoughts? If someone disagrees, I'd very much welcome it if they could create a good tag wiki.

Comment: Hurray, this got me the [tumbleweed badge](http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed)... which I had honestly not anticipated. I guess I'll ask the mods to add [tag:status-declined] to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry this didn't draw a response. I feel neutral about the tag; I can imagine that questions *only* about datasets are better on OpenData, questions here might feasibly pertain *in part* to datasets. Your logic is sound though I could conceive of searching for "noise datasets" or something seeking questions about dealing with noise.

I suppose that de facto there's likely no burnination here. I didn't know about [status-declined](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined); I am happy to apply it but am not strongly against this.

Comment: Thanks. Re "noise": I'd say a [tag:noise] tag would be more useful in marking questions that pertain to noise. I'd guess that half the questions here deal with datasets in one sense or another, in which case the [tag:dataset] tag simply does not add any information. But it seems like the community disagrees.